# Why to return a removed item?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

I’m currently learning about linked and doubly linked lists. In both topics, I don’t understand one thing. Why should we return the removed item while removing head or tail? For example,

```js
// Create your .removeHead() method below:
  removeHead() {
    const removedHead = this.head;
    
    if (!removedHead) {
      return;
    }
    
    this.head = removedHead.getNextNode()
    
    if (this.head) {
      this.head.setPreviousNode(null)
    }
    
    if (removedHead === this.tail) {
      this.removeTail();
    }
    
    return removedHead.data;
  }
```

Why do  `return removedHead.data`? Please, help me to understand. I just don't get it why by returning the item, we are removing it and how the programm actually interprets it under the hood? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I understand your question is that you think that by returning the head of the list, the function removes it from the list. That is not the case.

First of all try to read the code line by line and write each state of an imaginary linked list on a piece of paper. It will help you analyze the code:

The function starts by taking the existing head and saving it in removedHead.

Then it finds the next item in the list (next node) starting from the current head. Since the current head will be removed, this next node will become the new head and the function sets the previous node of this new head to null. A head does not have a previous node (the head is the first node and has nothing that comes before it). Please note that if the next node of the head to be removed is null, then there is no next node and the list is empty.

Finally, if the removed head is the last element in the list, that means that the head is also the tail (a list with one element has 1 head which is also the tail). In this case we need to remove the tail as well which sets the tail pointer to null somewhere else in the code. The function removeTail() accomplishes that.

As a final step the function gives you the data of the discarded head. This is not necessary and if that last line of code is removed, it will have no impact on the rest of the code. It is there as an added feature in case you need to do something with it.

Comment: @yavnelf, then you should consider marking the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Because this.head seems to have a data object which probably contains information on the removed item and potentially also information on whether the delete was successful or not. By returning it the calling routine gets this information which it may use - or simply ignore because the returned value doesn't need to be processed.

Just use your debugger and take a look at the object to understand its contents.